# Please help me ID this...castle and gates

Tags: set-identification

[image][image]

We've been given boxes after boxes of LEGO bricks...trying to piece them all together.  It's a blessing but also a great challenge !

Answer (score 6):

That would be [Attack On Weathertop](https://shop.lego.com/en-US/Attack-on-Weathertop-9472), from the Lord Of The Rings series. Looks like it's missing a fair few pieces, but it's still mostly intact.

EDIT: Oops, top picture didn't load before I posted. The gate is from [Mines Of Moria](https://shop.lego.com/en-US/The-Mines-of-Moria-9473); the fold-out hill is [Attack On Weathertop](https://shop.lego.com/en-US/Attack-on-Weathertop-9472).

Comment: I attempted to translate the runes above the gate in the Moria set, but they appear to be nonsense, chosen for aesthetics rather than a hidden message of some kind.

Comment: @maguirenumber6 Using the runes from the [The Hobbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirth#Runes_from_The_Hobbit), you get  "Diordie was here" or "Djordje was here" - [a reference](http://bricksetforum.com/discussion/comment/86125/#Comment_86125) to one of the sets designers.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid I must have been using the wrong Dwarvish alphabet :-)

Comment: Yep, he made up quite a few, with different transliterations of the same runes, which can make it a little hard to know initially which one has been used. I went for the one from The Hobbit as it was the variant I could remember the most from without having to look it up :$

Answer (score 2):

As per Lepidolite Mica's answer, the bottom picture is from [9472 Attack On Weathertop](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9472-1&name=Attack%20on%20Weathertop&category=%5BThe%20Hobbit%20and%20the%20Lord%20of%20the%20Rings%5D%5BThe%20Lord%20of%20the%20Rings%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) from the Lord Of The Rings Theme.

[image]

The top model is from another LOTR set, [9473 Mines Of Moria](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9473-1#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D). Neither of these sets are complete in your picture.

[image]